# Post increment operator not incrementing in for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, infinite-loop, post-increment

I'm doing some research about Java and find this very confusing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i = i++) {
  System.err.print("hoo... ");
}
```

This is never ending loop!

Anybody has good explanation why such thing happens?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i = i++) {
```

The above loop is essentially the same as: -

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i = i) {
```

the 3<sup>rd</sup> part of your `for` statement - `i = i++`, is evaluated as: -

```
int oldValue = i; 
i = i + 1;
i = oldValue;  // 3rd Step
```

---

You need to remove the assignment from there, to make it work: -

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
```

---

(On OP request from Comments)

### Behaviour of `x = 1; x = x++ + x++;` : -

As far as your issue as specified in the comment is concerned, the result of the following expression: -

```
x = 1; 
x = x++ + x++;
```

is obtained as follows: -

Let's mark different parts of the second statement: -

```
x = x++ + x++;
R    A     B
```

Now, first the RHS part `(A + B)` will be evaluated, and then the final result will be assignmed to `x`. So, let's move ahead.

First `A` is evaluated: -

```
old1 = x;  // `old1 becomes 1`
x = x + 1; // Increment `x`. `x becomes 2`
//x = old1; // This will not be done. As the value has not been assigned back yet.
```

Now, since the assignment of `A` to `R` is not done here, the 3rd step is not performed.

Now, move to `B` evaluation: -

```
old2 = x;  // old2 becomes 2. (Since `x` is 2, from the evaluation of `A`)
x = x + 1; // increment `x`. `x becomes 3`.
// x = old2; // This will again not be done here.
```

Now, to get the value of `x++ + x++`, we need to do the last assignment that we left in the evaluation of `A` and `B`, because now is the value being assigned in `x`. For that, we need to replace: -

```
A --> old1
B --> old2   // The last assignment of both the evaluation. (A and B)

/** See Break up `x = old1;` towards the end, to understand how it's equivalent to `A = old1; in case of `x = x++`, considering `x++ <==> A` in this case. **/
```

So, `x = x++ + x++`, becomes: -

```
x = old1 + old2;
  = 1 + 2;
  = 3;  // Hence the answer
```

---

### Break up of 3rd part of `x = x++`, to see how it works in `x = x++ + x++` case: -

Wonder why the replacement is done as `A --> old1` and not `x --> old1`, as in case of `x = x++`.

Take a deep look at `x = x++` part, specially the last assignment: -

```
x = oldValue;
```

if you consider `x++` to be `A` here, then the above assignment can be broken into these steps: -

```
A = oldValue;
x = A;
```

Now, for the current problem, it is same as: -

```
A = old1;
B = old2;
x = A + B;
```

I hope that makes it clear.

Comment: This is the only answer that explained the difference between `i = i++` and plain `i++`.

Comment: Okey, this looks possible but I found somewhere an example of `int x = 1; x = x++` and after that `x` is still `1` but here: `x = x++ + x++` x won't be still `1` or `2` but `3` - how??

Comment: Got curious about that and googled this, explaining why `i=i++` does not work https://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/PostIncrementOperatorAndAssignment

Comment: @emka86.. May be because `x++` is evaluated to `1`, but `x++ + x++` is evaluated to `3`. But still that's quite interesting. Will have a look at it in detail.

Comment: @emka86.. That really deserves a place for new question. You should ask it. that `x = x++ + x++;` one. For now, I'm trying to device the evaluation order.

Comment: @emka86.. Added some explanation about your doubt. You can have a look at the revised answer.

Answer (score 8):

You're using post-increment: `i = i++;`, it means something like this:

```
temp = i;
i = i + 1;
i = temp;
```

because [15.14.2 Postfix Increment Operator ++](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.14.2):

> The value of the postfix increment expression is the value of the variable **before** the new value is stored.

That is why you have the old value.

For-loop done right:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  System.err.print("hoo... ");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

because of i=i++

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10;  i++) {
  System.err.print("hoo... ");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

i++ will report the value of i, and THEN increment. This also means that you don't need to set i equal to i++, just change to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the statement `i=i++`,  this statement does three operations  in sequence to complete. these are two operations in `i++` and one assignment( `=` ) operation. These are;

`i++` does two operation before any operation

1. Returns `i`
2. Increments `i`

finally assignment operation

3. Assigns returned value

So `i` is incremented before assignment making it to have old value.

Lets see `i=i++` in the first loop( where `i = 0` ) with the three operations

1. returns `0` , it will not be assigned to `i` until the next operation is done
2. increments `i` ( `i= 0 + 1 = 1` )
3. assigns returned value `0` to `i`, ( `i = 0`), finally `i` having its old value.

In `i++` first `i` is returned, but immediately  before any operation is done it is incremented(`i` becomes `i+1` ), However we are yet  left with assignment operation to complete so that the returned value will be assigned to `i` making it to have old value, thereby  entering infinite loop.

so replace `i=i++` with `i++`or `i=i+1`