# How to use method with variables?

Tags: java

**Targer** - need to count how many numbers with 6 digit have same summ of left and right 3 digit

**What done** - prepared 3 methods:

*1-st* - counting summ of left 3 digit from number - works ok

```
private static int counterLeft3(int i) {
    int digitCounter=0;
    int summLeft3=0;
    while (digitCounter!=3){
        summLeft3=summLeft3+(i%10);
        i=i/10;
        digitCounter++;
    }
    return summLeft3;
}
```

*2-nd* - counting summ of right 3 digit from number - works ok

```
 private static int counterRight3(int i) {
    int summRight3=0;
    int buffer;
    int counter=0;
    while (counter!=3){
        summRight3=summRight3+(i%10);
        i=i/10;
        counter++;
    }
    buffer =i;
    summRight3=0;
    while (buffer!=0){
        summRight3=summRight3+(buffer%10);
        buffer=buffer/10;
    }
    return summRight3;
}
```

*3-dr* - cycle for counting q-ty of numbers - allways return 0. thnink - my mistake thomthing here :

```
private static void summCounter() {
    int counter=0;
    for (int i=111110; i<1000000; i++){
        if (counterRight3(i)==counterLeft3(i)){ 
        }
        counter = counter++;
    }
    System.out.println("Q-ty is " + counter);
}
```

**debug - 
example**

[image]

result for 1-st method

[image]

result for 2-nd method

[image]

**Question** - what wrong with 3-rd method, why it allways return just 0 and counter never increase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your *3rd* method the assignment: -

```
counter = counter++;
```

has no effect on `counter` value. After this assignment, `counter` remains `0` only. You need to remove the assignment part, and just have `increment` part: -

```
counter++;
```

And you need to do the increment inside your `if block` only when your left and right sum is equal.

**See also: -**

- [Post increment operator not incrementing in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571327/why-this-for-loop-never-ends/14571345#14571345)

Comment: Also this code needs to be inside the `if` block. You have `if (...) {} counter++;`. Needs to be `if (...) { counter++; }`.

Comment: @jlordo.. Damn! didn't notice it.