# java looping example with increment operator

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, operator-keyword, increment

I have a little doubt here,i have a code as

```
 int num=0;
 for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
   num=num++;
   System.out.print(num);
 }
```

why is the output always 00000

Comment: You have multiple syntax errors in your code? How does it run? int i notdefined, no semicolon after num++?

Comment: num=num++ where is ;   ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post increment operator not incrementing in for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571327/post-increment-operator-not-incrementing-in-for-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use num++;

```
int num=0;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
   num++;
   System.out.print(num);
}
```

Output **12345**

**num=num++;**

is equals to **num=num;**

**num=++num;**

is equals to **num=num+1;**

Comment: Op is asking for reason and you are providing the solutin

Answer (score 10):

The ++ operator increments num last, so when num is 0, you are setting it to 0 again.

It has to deal with how the ++ operator increments num, and what num is truly pointing to. To avoid it, just use num++

Interestingly enough, num=++num will correctly increment and assign the incremented value, though the whole purpose of the ++ operator, either pre or post, is that it modifies the value directly. You do not have to re-assign it back to the value.

Comment: Good answer. 'Self-increment' operators don't have to be assigned to their variable, trying to do so is a mistake! +1.

Answer (score 2):

```
num=num++;
```

is equal -

```
num = num;
num ++;
```

First it assign then it try to increment the num which is already assigned. For better calrification -

```
 0  iconst_0
 1  istore_1 [num]
 2  iconst_0
 3  istore_2 [i]
 4  goto 22
 7  iload_1 [num] // Load first
 8  iinc 1 1 [num] // incement but no reload
11  istore_1 [num] // store old load value
12  getstatic java.lang.System.out : java.io.PrintStream [16]
15  iload_1 [num]
16  invokevirtual java.io.PrintStream.print(int) : void [22]
19  iinc 2 1 [i]
22  iload_2 [i]
23  iconst_5
24  if_icmplt 7
27  return
```

if we consider `num=++num;`

then generated byte code would be -

```
 0  iconst_0
 1  istore_1 [num]
 2  iconst_0
 3  istore_2 [i]
 4  goto 22
 7  iinc 1 1 [num] // Increment 
10  iload_1 [num] // load the incremented value
11  istore_1 [num] // store the loaded incremented value
...
```

Comment: Not strictly correct. The order in which assignments are executed is arbitrary (not defined by the language). I assume that in the poster's problem, the assignment (to the original value) was being executed *after* the post-increment. Thus overwriting any increment.

Comment: Exactly. The language _does not define behaviour_ where assignments & increments are present, within the same statement. Neither do C/C++ (though there, the smallest unit of sequencing can be a comma-operator clause.) Corner-cases like this are left unspecified deliberately, to allow flexibility for optimization & discourage code from relying on highly-obscure/ or implementation-dependent outcomes.

Answer (score 1):

That what [postfix ++ does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5413593/1651233).

You can use:

```
num++;
System.out.print(num);
```

Comment: Has everyone lost their semicolons?

Answer (score 1):

`num=num++;`
Here you are using postfix ++ operator with assignment.So that means you assigned the value first and then incremented it.
So

```
 num = num++;
```

equivalent to

```
 num = num;//line1
 num+1;//line2
```

Deep look at *line2* .The result of `num+1` is not assigned to anything.So `num` is always have the value assigned at *line1*.i.e.,0 in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, In java `=` operator works as follows

`L.H.S=R.H.S`  right hand side value will assign to left hand side variable.

In here initial value of `num=0` and

`num=num++` this increment not influence in place to `num`. if you do `++num` it will effect at once in palace. so again you are assign `0` for `num`. So entire process this will happen continuously until loop stop.

Answer (score 1):

for explanation,

Post Increment(n++) : First execute the statement and then increase the value by one.

here, value of 'num++' is assigned to num and that is before increment and is 0.
so num will have always value 0.

you can use simply num++ there.